# Thread never allowed access to synchronized block of code

Tags: java, multithreading

The `Future` object is never able to obtain access to the synchronized block of code so it never finishes and never returns. There isn't anything accessing writeOut() besides the thread so I am not sure why it is block.

```
public class FileManager {
   private void writeOut() throws BusinessException {
    if(f.exists() && f.canWrite()) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f)) {
                String endLine = "\n";
                fileWriter.write("");
                for (Entry entry : directory) {
                    fileWriter.append(entry.getLastName());
                    fileWriter.append(CSV_DELIMITER);
                    fileWriter.append(entry.getFirstName());
                    fileWriter.append(CSV_DELIMITER);
                    fileWriter.append(entry.getPhoneNumber());
                    fileWriter.append(CSV_DELIMITER);
                    fileWriter.append(entry.getAddress());
                    fileWriter.append(endLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist or can't be written to");
    }
  }

   public void addEntry(Entry entryModel, boolean notify) {
      assert entryModel != null;
      synchronized (this) {
        AddEntryAction addAction = new AddEntryAction(entryModel, notify);
        AddEntryActor actor = new AddEntryActor(addAction);
        actor.execute();
        deleteActor(actor);
      }
   }
```

Here is the method that is called by `execute()`:

```
private void executeAsynchronously() {
    Callable<String> asyncTask = () -> {
        try {
            ServiceFw.fileManager.writeBack();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            notifyFailure();
        }
        return "write back operation";
    };
    future = executor.submit(asyncTask);
    Runnable poll = () -> {
        if(future!=null) {
            notifySuccess();
        } else {
            notifyFailure();
        }
    };
    poll.run();
}
```

Comment: `future` will not be `null` on failure. Also, a `future` object will be created even though the request hasn't finished, meaning the condition in the `Runnable` referenced by `poll` isn't logical. Might wanna read up on the docs of `Future`, as [blocking is in the contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) of `Future#get()`

Comment: I'm right on the edge of closing this question because there's way too much code, and most of it is irrelevant. Please reduce the code to the absolute minimum that shows the problem.

Comment: I just cleaned it up and removed much of the code

Comment: So where you call writeOut?

Comment: @alpert writeOut() is called in notifySuccess()